# Regex with dynamic name not change string

Tags: php

I am beginner php developer. This is my first post here.
I have dynamic content and I need add alt tag for all my images (if not exists).

I have this code:

```
$content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <img src="https://www.name.com.pl/assets/images/about/4.jpg"> consectetur adipisicing <b>elit.</b> Dolores ducimus eius sint veritatis.
<img src="https://www.name.com.pl/upload/DZ_AREA_ATTRACTION/thumbs10/491cf6db24dc40325250fdeeac3157fa.jpg"> At, doloribus dolorum earum enim fugiat in, ipsa odit optio perspiciatis quibusdam quis sunt unde ut voluptas.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores ducimus eius sint veritatis. <img src="https://www.name.com.pl/upload/DZ_AREA_ATTRACTION/bfcbae278cabee99756d275b68603279.jpg" alt="abc"> At, <u>doloribus</u> dolorum earum enim fugiat in, ipsa odit optio perspiciatis <img src="https://www.name.com.pl/upload/DZ_AREA_ATTRACTION/b65cf0990317814f636b38ec7efe574b.jpg"> quibusdam quis sunt unde ut voluptas.';


$content = html_entity_decode($_POST['content']);
    $title = $_POST['title'];

    $pattern = '#<img(?!.*alt=")(.+src="(([^"]+/)?(.+)\..+)"[^ /]*)( ?\/?)>#i';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, "<img$1 alt=\"qqqqq\">", $content);
    $content1 = strip_tags($content, '<img>');
    //echo $content1 . "<br/><br/><br/>";
```

It's work fine. When I run this code, $content has alt tags (new - if not exist, exist - when is available in string).

I need change this code to get dynamic alt.

When I change this line from:

```
$content = preg_replace($pattern, "<img$1 alt=\"qqqqq\">", $content);
```

to:

```
$content = preg_replace($pattern, "<img$1 alt=\"$title\">", $content);
```

this is not working :( Alt is not adding. How can I repair it?

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```php
$content = html_entity_decode($_POST['content']);

$title = "Your dynamic alt text"; // Replace this with your dynamic alt text retrieval logic

$pattern = '#<img(?!.*alt=")(.+src="(([^"]+/)?(.+)\..+)"[^ /]*)( ?\/?)>#i';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, "<img$1 alt=\"$title\">", $content);
$content1 = strip_tags($content, '<img>');

echo $content1;
```